# Uploading a file to GAE with Play! Framework

Tags: google-app-engine, playframework, siena

What is the best way of uploading files to Google App Engine Blobstore with Play! Framework, using Siena and GAE module?

I have tried declaring a Blob field in my Model:

```
public Blob image;
```

And a method to attach the file:

```
public void attachImage(byte[] bytes) {
    this.image = new Blob(bytes);
}
```

I don't really know how to test this since the CrudSiena module doesn't display an upload field. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Blob is a type managed by GAE datastore but it's different from GAE Blobstore!

If you use byte[] instead of Blob in your model, does it work with CrudSiena?

Comment: Thank you, I managed to get the field in CrudSiena. But it seems like the file isn't uploaded, the `image` attribute is an empty byte array (length 0).

Comment: Is the field rendered as a file upload input in the CRUD? Did you reset your DataStore completely to be sure?

Comment: Yes, the field is a file upload. I have tried with an empty datastore, and I still have en empty array of bytes. The weird thing is that nothing is displayed once the form is sent, is there supposed to be a thumbnail or something?

Comment: do you have a sample of your model to verify I don't see anything weird?